# plotting one specific point on a line, matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 2 lists which I plot as a line:

```
x =  [ 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9]
y = [ 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
plt.plot(x,y)
```

Then I'd want to plot a marker, e.g. 'x', on that line at a point which is not specified in my list, e.g.

```
x = 0.2
```

Is there a straightforward way of doing this?

Comment: use the interpolation function from numpy to get the y-value, and then make another call to `plot`

Comment: that works great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The equation for your "line" is `y = 5 * abs(x - 0.5) + 2`. You can therefore plot a point using something like

```
plt.plot(0.2, 3.5, 'x')
```

Where `3.5 = 5.0 * abs(0.2 - 0.5) + 2.0`.

Alternatively, you can use @PaulH's solution and use [`numpy.interp(0.2, x, y)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html). This is probably a better general solution if your data is not really an absolute value function except locally.

Comment: My function changes in each loop and I only need to plot one point so the numpy solution seems to do the trick. I guess if there was a python function which would take your xy values and come up with an equation that solves it then that could work as well. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. Force of habit. Fixed.